# Symfony not finding a custom class

Tags: php, symfony

In my folder "/Vendor/User/Admin" I created a new custom class (Adminuser.php)

```
namespace \User\Admin;
class Adminuser {
    public $username;
    public $password;       
}
```

Now Im trying to use it in a controller:

```
namespace Section\AdminBundle\Controller;
use \User\Admin;
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $AdminUser = new \User\Admin\Adminuser();  // CLASS NOT FOUND!!
        .......
```

Why is this happening?, the namespace is wrong? (I tried a few options..)
Im very begginer with Symfony, sorry.

Comment: First guess: You should not prefix namespaces with `\` in the `use` and `namespace` statements

Comment: I tried to delete them, but still the problem, thanks

Comment: The user class should go somewhere under AdminBundle and not the vendor directory.

Comment: Well but some classes I saw might be outside just to reuse them along more bundles, isnt it?

Comment: Then it should live in src/User/Admin/Adminuser.php

Comment: I like that idea, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 main issues.

**The First**

When declaring a namespace you should not start with a `\`

```
 namespace \User\Admin;
```

Should just be:

```
namespace User\Admin;
```

**The Second**

If you want those classes to live in your Vendors Dir then you need to make sure the class is being autoloaded by symfony correctly. To do this we will use composer.

In your composer.json you will want to change this section from:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
```

TO:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" },
    "psr-0": { "": "vendor/User/Admin" }
},
```

Then composer will add classes under that folder to the available namespaces and you will be able to access it as expected.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the first "\" in the namespace, as the comments said. So the first file is:
    namespace User\Admin;
    class Adminuser {
      public $username;
      public $password;
    }
if the problem persist check your autoloading configuration, maybe the right way would be using src dir to develop your code, not vendor :S